# Installing TFS 2010 build service on a separate domain

Tags: tfs

What I am trying to achieve is to setup a new build controller in my laptop running on XP SP3 in domain X, with Application tier running on 2008 Server in Y domain. Since they are running on  different domain to I created a common local user with same password in both machines. On Application tier I have granted that user Admin rights and even added to “TFS Administration console users”. So when I log-on with the local user in Y domain all TFS service are up and running. 
Installing build service on XP has no issues with the local user, but when I try to start the controller or Agent it fails with  error 
**“There was no endpoint listening at that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.”**
However if I install build service on a machine in Y domain I am able to add new controller and agent without any issues.
I have tried various solution suggested on net like setting IE connection properties or adding TFS machine domain trusted sites but nothing have changed so far. Any pointer to how to resolve would much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to run the Build Controller on your laptop with a service account of the Y domain. If your laptop can make authentication requests to the Y domain, it should work.

If you run the Build Controller with a X domain account you can make it in theory, but it's not something easy, an approbation between both domains must be created on Y and Y must be able to connect and authenticate X domain account (so it's a two ways approbation). Then don't forget to put the X domain account in the Build group membership of TFS for it to get the requested permissions. However this scenario is almost never used and I think you'll run into a lot of troubles. Try the first solution I gave to you.

Comment: Hi Nockawa I already tried your solution, but its still the same issue. I first thought that it might be my virus scan that was blocking port 9191 but even adding it to exception list did not helped.

Comment: You succeeded to configure the Build Controller with an account of the Y domain? I mean does the TFS Configuration gave you an error or it's fine for it ?
Something else you could do: log on the TFS Server (directly or with RDP), try to ping your laptop, if it succeeds, do a "telnet <YourLaptopNameOrIP> 9191" (to check there's no firewall issue), if it's also working open Internet Explorer and browse to the URL of your Build Controller web service (the URL should be in your error message)